# Toggle class of another div on click of a new div. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I have a toggle menu, and I am adding a search toggle menu, and I can't get the jquery to do what I want.

If you click on the search toggle, I want the search overlay to show up (which I have working), but then I want the same x close button (from the main toggle overlay) to appear in the top left, and I want the search toggle to dissappear.

As of now, it is going back to the main overlay when I hit close, and the non-active main toggle is still showing, instead of the active x.

Here is my live website:  http://acetronaut.com

I'm going insane...

JQuery:

```
// burger overlay menu
  $('.acetrnt-toggle').on('click',function(){
    $("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');


  });

 // search toggle

  $('.acetrnt-search-toggle').on('click',function(){
    $("#acetrnt-search-overlay").fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('.acetrnt-toggle.active');
    $(this).hide('.acetrnt-toggle');

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.acetrnt-search-toggle').on('click',function(){
  var $icon = $('.acetrnt-search-toggle > i')
  $icon.toggleClass('fa-search fa-times');
  $('.acetrnt-toggle').hide()
});
```

Edit

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9mvh5be/)

Comment: // That is what I was thinking, and that works for showing the active state of acetrnt toggle, and hiding the search toggle, but when I click on the active .acetrnt toggle, it brings up the main menu overlay.

Comment: @AceLong , look the fiddle please, after this code you may move the icon to the top if you want

Comment: I don't want to use an icon though, but thanks.  I'm thinking maybe something to do with click states...?